# Android app で画像を複数枚並べて表示したい

Tags: android, java, android-studio

Android Studioでアプリを作っています。
画像を複数枚並べて表示させたいのですが、現在１枚しか画面に表示されません。
今、２枚並べて表示させる処理を行っているのですが、どうして１枚しか表示されないのでしょうか？
activity_main.xmlには

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bigfig"
       android:src="@drawable/bigfig" />

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/feminine"
        android:src="@drawable/feminine" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

のように記載し、
MainActivity.java には

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.feminine);
        ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bigfig);
    }

}
```

と記載しました。
最終的には７枚画像を画面に表示させたいのですが、どのようなメソッドを使えば表示させられますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RelativeLayoutは表示位置を指定しない場合、子要素はすべて左上に配置されます。
画像が1枚しか表示されていないのは、画像が重なってしまい見えていないだけです。
おそらく最後のfeminineの画像だけが表示されている状態だと思いますが、その下にbigfigの画像とHello World!の文字列も存在しています（子要素は最初の要素から順番に描画されるためです）。

対策は2つあります。

#### RelativeLayoutをLinearLayoutに変更する

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bigfig"
        android:src="@drawable/bigfig" />

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/feminine"
        android:src="@drawable/feminine" />


</LinearLayout>
```

LinearLayoutを使う場合、orientationで並べる方向を指定する必要があります。
この場合は縦に並べる指定になります。

#### 子要素の表示位置を指定する

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bigfig"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"
        android:src="@drawable/bigfig" />

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/feminine"
        android:layout_below="@id/bigfig"
        android:src="@drawable/feminine" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

layout_belowで指定したIDを持つ要素の下に表示されます。
他にも、指定したIDの要素の右に配置したり、親要素の中心に配置したりといった指定方法も可能です。